# Change Django Users List Display

Tags: django, admin

I am trying to change the Users view in Django Admin to show different fields (now it shows by default: username, email address, first name, last name, staff status) I have tried this in the admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Register your models here.


UserAdmin.list_display = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'last_login']

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

However I cannot get my admin Users view to change.
 Is there anything else I need to do? I am using Django 2.0

Answer (score 15):

Quite simply: define your own `UserAdmin`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'last_login']

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `MyUserAdmin` inherit from `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin`?

Comment: @dm295 no it "should" not - it _can_ if you want to inherit other features from `auth.admin.UserAdmin` indeed, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: I got this to work once I created a user with first/last name, and email. I was just creating a user with the username and password . thanks

Comment: Would this go in a file called `user.py` or in `admin.py`?

Comment: @DavidRhoden Django expects your admin modules to be named 'admin.py' (that's how it discovers them).